# get items of a list that matches items of another list in a for loop with Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm really new to Python so first of all sorry if I'm asking something too obvious... I have a list of strings like:

```
a = ['car/red/1','car/red/2','bike/red/1','bike/red/3','skate/blue/1','skate/blue/2']
```

And another list with substrings like:

```
b = ['car/red','bike/red','skate/blue']
```

How can I iterate list "a" extracting everytime the matches of an item in b?
I want something like:

`for i in b:
    matches = [x for x in a if i in x]
    print matches`

So the first pass of this would print 'car/red/1' and 'card/red/2', the second would print 'bike/red/1' and 'bike/red/3' and the third would print 'skate/blue/1' and 'skate/blue/2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in b:
    print [x for x in a if item in x]
```

The above will return

```
['car/red/1', 'car/red/2']
['bike/red/1', 'bike/red/3']
['skate/blue/1', 'skate/blue/2']
```

We are traversing each b_item in `b` and then using list comprehension to print a new array of any a_item from `a` of which b_item is a substring

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help. I know there must be more precise approach. But give the following code a try

```
a = ['car/red/1','car/red/2','bike/red/1','bike/red/3','skate/blue/1','skate/blue/2']

b = ['car/red','bike/red','skate/blue']

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i in j:
            print j
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expectation, I might want to use startwith.

```
a = ['car/red/1','car/red/2','bike/red/1','bike/red/3','skate/blue/1','skate/blue/2']
b = ['car/red','bike/red','skate/blue']

for ii in b:
    matches = [x for x in a if x.startswith(ii)]
    print(matches)
```

Result is the following:

```
['car/red/1', 'car/red/2']
['bike/red/1', 'bike/red/3']
['skate/blue/1', 'skate/blue/2']
```